# Reading div content of an external web page in c# ASP .Net

Tags: html, asp.net, dom, traversal

I have a plan of developing a web site, in that i have to read the content of an external web page. Is there any way to achieve the same in c# asp.net since i am little familiar with this language.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
   some title goes here
</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Container">
       <div id="Main_Contents">
          <div class="news">Some contents here.</div>
          <div class="news">Some contents here. Some more here.</div>
          <div class="news">Some contents here. Few more contents are here</div>
          <div class="UnWanted">Unnecessary contents presents here</div>
          <div class="news">Some contents here.</div>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Assume that, above like page is an external page. Now my intention is to read the content of the div whose class is **'news'** i.e., `<div class="news">`
**not that div with 'UnWanted' class**. There might be more number of div's like this in a page and i have to get all of them in an order.

I have done the same in PHP using html_dom library, but now i am switching over to ASP .Net

Comment: This is the job for [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: hi @Andrei, i tried using that but the problem is, that HtmlAgilityPack will return all the innerHTML text. There maybe nested div present in a page. Then how to do?

Comment: please answer my question....

Comment: Agility pack can do different things, so your problems sounds strange. Post a code snippet of how are you using it